# Address Geocoding returns invalid result using Google Geocoder

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I am working on an aplication that parses a list of addresses and gets their geolocation, in order to perform a proximity search.

I am using the GoogleMaps API v3 and the Google geocoder.

The problem that I am facing has to do with a specific address:

Address: Nieuwe Haven 233

Postcode: 3117 AB

City: Schiedam

Country: Netherlands

So to the point. Using google maps in my browser if I search for the above address everything works fine. [Here is a link](https://www.google.nl/maps/preview#!q=Nieuwe+Haven+233,+Schiedam,+Netherlands)

When I use the Geocoder to get the location I  get the center of this City and not the address.

Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nieuwe+Haven++233%2C+%EF%BB%BFSchiedam%2C+Netherlands&sensor=false

Why is this happening. What am I missing on the geocoder ?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bad unicode space before city.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nieuwe+Haven+233%2C+%EF%BB%BFSchiedam%2C+Netherlands&sensor=false

%EF%BB%BF - this is the problem.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nieuwe+Haven+233%2C+Schiedam%2C+Netherlands&sensor=false

This is correct url format.

Comment: @Petr B.  What about this one:   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=MALM%D6%20SWEDEN    Am I able to put the o-umlaut in the URL using %D6, or should I convert it to O-without-umlaut?

Comment: MALM%C3%96%20SWEDEN It's better to use urlEncode on your query string (%C3%96 = Ö). It's because api use UTF-8 encoding and not UTF-16 (0xC3 0x96 = 0x00D6). And google geocoding is clever enough to find city with or without umlaut.